# Display only the first child of a book

Tags: views, 10

I have a book "continent".
Child are like this :
Continent > Country > State >cities > Street

There are several countries, several states, several cities.

When I visit a State, a City or streets, I want to have a block to display the Country (the first child of the book).

What I tried to do in Views:
Relationship : Book parent
Contextual filters : Node ID with the relationship Book parent
Filter : depth = 2

It only displays the child ...

Do you have any idea about how to display a specific parent from a visited book page?

*Sorry for my bad English.*